# Solder balls or solder paste for reballing?

Tags: bga, rework

So, I'm planning on doing a reball for the graphics chip of my Pavilion DV4-1212LA.

It's going to be the first time so I have to buy the required tools, like a suction pencil for lifting the IGP, fine tweezers and such. I already have solved some of the basic equipment like the pre-heater (the "pre-heat station", is a cardboard box covered in aluminum foil. It actually works really good), the heat gun, flux, desoldering wick and IPA.

The thing is that I don't know if I should buy solder balls or solder paste. I do know that for both it's strictly necessary to have the stencil for alignment and ease of procedure. The thing is that if I use solder balls, I don't know what size to use.

I looked a bit for any datasheet from AMD, but all I was able to find was the datasheet for an IGP that is a model higher ([AMD RS880](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/46112.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiot8XQ2Iv_AhVNiJUCHbWRAUYQFnoECC0QAQ&usg=AOvVaw3AruAPG1i7SmVRa_pDufQW)) than mine (ATI RS780M), but has the same package (528-Pin FCBGA).

The datasheet itself doesn't mentions nothing specific about "Solder Ball size", but it does mention things like z-height ball radius, and pad diameter, but to be sure I wanted to ask here instead of risking it